# btrfs error failed to clone extents during incremental backup

Tags: btrfs

I'm attempting to perform a backup to an external hard drive. Both the native drive and external drive use a BTRFS filesystem. I do this by first creating a read-only snapshot of my home directory:

```
# btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /home /.snapshots/home/BACKUP
```

Followed by a send/receive to the backup drive:

```
# btrfs send /.snapshots/home/BACKUP | btrfs receive /.backup/home
```

I get this output:

```
At subvol /.snapshots/home/BACKUP
At subvol BACKUP
ERROR: failed to clone extents to matt/.local/share/Anki2/Matt/collection.anki2: Invalid argument
```

where the error occurs after a minute or so. I tried with several different snapshots and got the same error on each. Moreover, I couldn't find that file in any of the snapshots. I thought this might be some sort of disk corruption error, so I booted into a USB OS image and ran

```
# btrfs check --repair /dev/mapper/...
```

on the unmounted filesystem. This reported no errors. After booting back into the filesystem, I tried the backup again and got the same error. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

---

**EDIT**

As per Emmanuel Rosa's comment, I tried

```
# btrfs scrub start -B /
```

which exited without errors. The issue is still present after the scrub.

---

**EDIT 2**

I wasn't able to figure out what was wrong with this. I ended up just deleting the local file and then it worked again.

---

**EDIT 3**

While deleting files temporarily suspends the issue, new files are often created that create the same error, so this really isn't resolved. sqlite files seem to be particularly problematic.

Comment: Oh, boy. `btrfs check --repair` is the LAST thing one should run. See `man btrfs-check`. `btrfs scrub` may be useful. Check `man btrfs-scrub` to see if it fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `btrfs-check repair` and for pointint out `scrub`. Unfortunately, scrub didn't find any errors and I got the same error.

Comment: Do any of the `btrfs subvolume {find-new,list,show}` commands show any surprises for your subvolumes?

Comment: As far as I can tell those all look normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in the Linux kernel, which was fixed by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9722b10148504c4153a74a9c89725af271e490fc). I discovered this by posting [a question on the btrfs mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/87blnsuv7m.fsf@gmail.com/T/#u). Upgrading the kernel resolved the issue.